# TikZ/PGF drawing Sierpinski triangle for predefined iteration-level

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-decorations

I would like to draw some iteration levels of the Sierpinski triangle. Lets say I'm ok for Iteration 0-4: line, triangle, first times devided triangle (triforce ;) ), ...

Is there a way to do it like the Koch snowflake?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.fractals}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration=Koch snowflake]
     \draw decorate{ decorate{ decorate{ decorate{ (0,0) -- (3,0) }}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I can't find any nice solution in the www.

Further I would like to print only a part of the next lvl. Lets say we have the basic triangle of step 1. In step 2 you will devide the whole triangle in 4 congruent triangles. I would like only to print the next step in the upper part.

(for each Step until 4)

The last mission I am facing: I want to add three curved lines, from each edge of the basic triangle to the right of the triangle and enter some Text. So they shall stop in a neighbourhood of the text. I guess, if I finished the previous step, this one might be pretty easy.

thank you all for reading and helping :)

Comment: Hey, I'm not interested in the koch-curve. I needs to draw the sierpinski triangle.

Comment: @Shalec The linked question is about drawing Sierpinski triangles - not Koch curves. Look at the top of your question for the link there. (Not the links in Sebastiano 's comment.)

Comment: Ty, I saw that thread, but it seemed to be a bit to difficult and not in my sense. I just wants to draw such a triangle only filled with lines, nothing colored or really filled. 
There is mentioned about the lindenmayersystems. Is there a docu about this?

Comment: Just use `\draw` rather than `\fill` if you want to draw rather than filling. The Ti*k*Z manual covers the lindenmayersystems library as it is built-in. Jake's answer shows you how to use it to draw these triangles. I don't understand what you mean by 'not in my sense'. If you want a Sierpinski triangle which is not a Sierpinski triangle in the sense of a Sierpinski triangle, you need to explain that, say, by 'Sierpinski triangle', you mean 'crescent moon' or whatever.